# Facebook SDK 3 for Android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, version, android-2.0-eclair

I need to integrate my android app with facebook. I would like to use the new Facebook SDK (3.0) but in the documentation it says the min sdk version is 8.
I would like to support api level 7 as miminum.

Is thete any way i can use the sdk?.

I also cant seem to find any documentation for the old version (the link in github points to the new documentation.)

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that only 8 and up is supported.

The legacy documentation is to be found at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/

Comment: Thanks. Do you think its a good idea to use the lecacy version now or should i change to min sdk to 8?

Comment: Bear in mind that the SDK 3 is still in beta, so you should use it for production use with caution. That said, it is of course the platform we will be supporting in the future.

PS it should also be backward compatible with the 2.x SDK.

Answer (score 0):

in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

> You'll need to have the Android 2.2 (API 8) components installed in
>   order to use the Facebook SDK.